# Numpy boolean indexing issue

Tags: python, numpy

Here is my code snippet that uses numpy

```
import numpy as np
n = 10
arr = np.array(range(n))
print(arr)
selection = [i % 2 == 0 for i in range(n)]
print(selection)
neg_selection = np.invert(selection)
print(neg_selection)

print(arr[selection])
print(arr[neg_selection])
```

The above code prints:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
[False  True False  True False  True False  True False  True]
[1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
[1 3 5 7 9]
```

the last two expected prints are:

```
[0 2 4 6 8]
[1 3 5 7 9]
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: What are you trying to do? This this a convoluted way to extract odd and even numbers

Comment: No, this is not for extracting odds and evens. I have a dataset of 'N' records in ndarray. I need to separate it into `test` and `train` based on index of items ( thats the protocol, no random shuffling allowed). In my actual case, every 7th item in the array goes to `test` and the rest goes to `train`. Here I used `2` instead of `7` and a simple 1D array instead of my complex array to simplify the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like numpy has trouble dealing with `list` of `boolean`s.

```
n = 10
arr = np.array(range(n))
selection = [i % 2 == 0 for i in range(n)]
neg_selection = np.invert(selection)

print(type(selection), arr[selection])
print(type(neg_selection), arr[neg_selection])
```

It produced:

```
<type 'list'> [1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0]
<type 'numpy.ndarray'> [1 3 5 7 9]
```

Noticed that the trouble here is due to `<type 'list'>`.
So, change the selection object to numpy array

```
selection = np.array([i % 2 == 0 for i in range(n)])
```

Or, even simpler:

```
selection = arr % 2 == 0
```

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [63]: arr=np.arange(10)
In [64]: arr
Out[64]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [65]: mask = [n%2==0 for n in arr]
In [66]: mask
Out[66]: [True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False, True, False]
```

Trying to index with this list:

```
In [67]: arr[mask]
/usr/local/bin/ipython3:1: FutureWarning: in the future, boolean array-likes will be handled as a boolean array index
  #!/usr/bin/python3
Out[67]: array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0])
```

It's treating your list as a list of index integers, not booleans; same as:

```
In [72]: arr[[3,0,2,0,1,0,5,0,2]]
Out[72]: array([3, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 5, 0, 2])
```

I wondered why you used `np.invert`, but then realized that with a list, `~` doesn't work:

```
In [68]: arr[~mask]
...

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'list'
```

`invert` turns the list into an array and does the `not`

```
In [69]: np.invert(mask)
Out[69]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
In [70]: arr[np.invert(mask)]
Out[70]: array([1, 3, 5, 7, 9])
```

and we can `not` that array:

```
In [71]: arr[~np.invert(mask)]
Out[71]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

Or if I create the mask `array` right from the start:

```
In [73]: mask = np.array([n%2==0 for n in arr])
In [74]: arr[mask]
Out[74]: array([0, 2, 4, 6, 8])
```

So basically, don't try to use a boolean list as a mask.  Use a boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can (should) write:

```
arr = np.arange(n) # elements of arr have the same type as n (int, float, complex, etc)
arr = np.arange(n, dtype=int)
arr = np.arange(n, dtype=float)
```

depending on what type you want for `arr`.